# How to store CGContext state in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, cgcontext, cgcontextref

I am new to the CGContext world. 
I need to create a stack of CGContext(s) in a NSMutableArray.

1. I have a valid PDFContext created with UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
2. I'm passing this context to a method as an argument

   `-(void) drawTo:(CGContextRef) context{}`
3. First I identify the current context with:

   `CGContextRef curCon = context;`
4. NSLog value:

   `context:<CGContext 0x6b79d60>`
5. Then I attempt to make a copy of the current context:

   `CGContextRef conCopy = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`
6. Then I add it to my NSMutableArray:

   `[myMutableArray* addObject:(id)conCopy];`
7. Then I list the content of the NSMutableArray:

   `after an object added:<__NSArrayM 0x6b7e850>(<CGContext 0x6b79d60>)`

And I see that the added value is the same context as originally sent to this method as an argument and not the copy.

What am I missing here ? Or perhaps it's not possible to store the status of current context in a NSMutableArray ? I understand that paths would not get saved, that's fine. I need to save anything and everything about the current context that can be saved.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly. But what's the real problem you're trying to solve? `CGContextSaveGState()` does what you're asking for, but only within the scope of the current context. `CGLayer` can effectively create contexts that you can carry around (though you still can't serialize them).

If your real goal is to save non-path state in a copyable form, then you can create a copyable object by calling all the `CGContextGet...` methods and storing their results. Then you can call `CGContextSet...` on them to make a new context. It's tedious, but should not be difficult. (Though it does raise the question of why. It feels like a very odd thing to be doing.)

Comment: thank you. I think I'll just use CGContextSaveGState() for now since I'm only working with one context for now.

Answer (score 0):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` does no create a copy. The returned context is there one you created using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`.

Comment: thank you. do you know if there is a way to make a copy of it and store it in NSMutableArray ? Or if not a copy then the state information from it